# Como verificar em C se o ficheiro está vazio?

Tags: c, arquivo

Boa noite,

Estou a trabalhar com C, e acontece que tenho uma função ou método que tem de imprimir para um ficheiro os dados, as marcações de refeição,respeitantes a alunos que marcaram refeição no sistema.

No metodo o sistema têm de verificar se esse ficheiro está vazio e se estiver vazio simplesmente imprime para o ficheiro `fprintf(filetmp, "%d %s %s %s \n", num, nome, subnome, meal);`

Se o ficheiro já tiver por exemplo 2 refeicoes marcadas pelos alunos, o sistema tem que as ler e imprimir também para `filetmp`

Acontece que já tentei comparar o ficheiro verificando se o mesmo está vazio, ou se tem alguma refeicao, verifiquei e consultei a internet para tal e apesar de existir, segundo sei uma funcao `ftell(file)` que permite determinar segundo me pareceu se o ficheiro esta vazio ou nao eu nao estou a conseguir de nenhuma maneira testar se o ficheiro tem ou nao alguma refeicao.

Tentei tambem o `feof(file)` mas acontece que simplesmente fico sem o ficheiro. Como será que posso alterar o código para ele verificar se o ficheiro está vazio, e para verificar se o ficheiro tem alguma refeicao.

```
void PrintMealToFIle(int num, char nome[100], char subnome[250])
    {
        size_t size;
        int i=0, j=0;
        struct Food f;
        struct CantinaAlunoFood aluno;
        const char *filename = "db-cantinameals.txt";
        FILE *file, *filetmp;
        filetmp = fopen("cantinatmp.txt", "w");
        file = fopen(filename, "r");
        size = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        //size = ftell(file);
        while (!(feof(file)))
        {

            if (ftell(file)==0)//se esta vazio
                //fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
                //size = ftell(file);

                fprintf(filetmp, "%d %s %s %s \n", num, nome, subnome, meal);

            if (ftell(file)!=0)
            {
                fscanf(file, "%d %s %s %s ", &aluno.id, aluno.name, aluno.subname, aluno.refeicao);
                fprintf(filetmp, "%d %s %s %s \n", num, nome, subnome, meal);
                fclose(filetmp);
                fclose(file);


                if (remove(filename) == 0)
                {
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("Ficheiro removido com sucesso\n");
                }

                else
                    perror("Problema a remover ficheiro ");

                if (rename("cantinatmp.txt", filename) == 0)
                {
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("Ficheiro bem renomeado");
                }

                else
                    perror("Problema ");

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Não vou nem tentar analisar o código porque ele parece estar em estado semi acabado mas o caminho que você está tentando parece correto. Acho que você precisaria detalhar mais o problema ou produzir um código mais fácil de analisar o problema. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Fazer `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); if(ftell(file) == 0)` certamente funciona.

Comment: `fopen(..., "a")` ... abrir o ficheiro em mode *"append"* acrescenta o que se escrever no fim do que já lá existe.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode verificar qual o tamanho do arquivo e então verificar se está vazio.

```
int get_size(const char* file_name)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if(file == NULL)
        return 0;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(file);
    fclose(file);

    return size;
}
```

---

Exemplo, verificando se o arquivo `teste.txt` está vazio:

```
if(get_size("teste.txt") == 0)
{
    printf("O arquivo esta vazio.");
}
else
{
    printf("O arquivo nao esta vazio.");
}
```

Comment: O segundo `fseek` é desnecessário.

Comment: Realmente, removi.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um sistema de repetição básica para verificar se há algo existente no arquivo

```
int main(){

   char Arquivo(Array);    //Variáveis
   int i=0;

   FILE *Abrir;   //Abrir e ler o arquivo
   Abrir=fopen(Arquivo,"rt");

      fscanf(Abrir,%c,&Arquivo(i));

      if (Arquivo(i) == Null){ // Condição Se
         printf("Arquivo Vazio");
      } else {printf("Arquivo com dados");}
      break;

   printf("A partir daqui vc resolve o que fazer");

   fclose(Abrir);   //fechando ponteiro
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aquele `break` dentro do seu loop não vai dar muito certo, não testei mas só de 'bater o olho' dá pra ver que o loop será rodado uma única vez.

Comment: Esse código tem outros erros.

Comment: Não acho que este código compile do jeito que está.